# Creating threads and providing argument to the function in C

Tags: c, pthreads, printf, void-pointers

I am currently creating threads and I would like to print out the "thread number" of each thread I make. For example:

```
void* thread_function(void* arg){
    printf("This is thread # %d\n", *(int*)arg);
    return NULL;
}


pthread_t id;
int main()
    for(int i  = 0; i< 5; i++){
    pthread_create(&id, NULL, thread_function, &i);
    }
    //do some other stuff
    return 0;
}
```

So basically, for the first thread, I want it to say:

```
This is thread # 0
```

However, for some reason it gives me random numbers like

```
This is thread # -56465645645
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pased *pointer to* `i` that will vanish after exiting the `for` loop instead of *value of* `i`.

Try using `(void*)i` instead of `&i` in function `main()` and 
passing `(int)arg` instead of `*(int*)arg` in function `thread_function()`.

(conversion between pointers and intergers is implementation-defined)

Comment: I tried int i = (int)arg, but i am getting the warning :  cast from pointer to integer of different size

Comment: OKay so it seems to work, but I am getting the warning as i mentioned above.